# How to convert specific column values to lowercase

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am trying to figure it out if CsvHelper can manipulate specific column values in the CSV when reading the file.

For example, based on the setup below, I would like to receive the email values always as lowercase:

```
public class MyCsvEntity : ICsvEntity
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string DirectManager { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> DynamicColumns { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
public sealed class MyCsvMap : ClassMap<MyCsvEntity>
{
    public MyCsvMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Email).Name("Email");
        Map(m => m.FirstName).Name("First Name");
        Map(m => m.LastName).Name("Last Name");
        Map(m => m.DirectManager).Name("Direct Manager");
    }
}
```

I've tried to find documentation and to look for any built-in configuration that would help me accomplish this, but to no avail. For the moment I'm reading the data exactly as it is in the .csv file, and performing the `ToLower()` elsewhere. If someone knows how to accomplish this with CsvHelper or provide any insight, much appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't something like this work: `public string Email { get { return this.email; } set { this.email = value.ToLower(); } }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to use the `Convert` method on the `Map` for this:

```cs
public sealed class MyCsvMap : ClassMap<MyCsvEntity>
{
    public MyCsvMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Email).Name("Email").Convert(row => row.GetField("Email").ToLower());
        Map(m => m.FirstName).Name("First Name");
        Map(m => m.LastName).Name("Last Name");
        Map(m => m.DirectManager).Name("Direct Manager");
    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware, if you have multiple names applied, that `.GetField()` only checks for the name specified. This means you have to use null-coalesce or something else in this case like `.Name("A").Name("B").Convert(row => (row.GetField("A") ?? row.GetField("B")).ToLower())` (but I'm currently unsure if `.GetField()` throws or returns null).

Comment: @Oliver Unfortunately, it does throw an exception if that header is missing. I think you would have to do something like this. `.Name("A", "B").Convert(args => { args.Row.TryGetField("A", out string result);  if (result == null) { args.Row.TryGetField("B", out result); } return result.ToLower();  });`

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the trick! Just a small note, I had to write it like this:
Convert(args => args.Row.GetField("Email").ToLower());
The specific field is set as mandatory and I already have a safety check inside the parser that ensures the field is present, so I don't think I need to worry about a missing header.